# Guzzle HTTP, Laravel Http Client, why my code is slow?

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I'm using Guzzle Http client with Laravel 8.34.0, My code is very slow to read just a few lines of json file. Is there something wrong with my code??

```
$result = Http::get($ip . '/hb/market/detail/merged?symbol=' . $symbol)->json();
if($result['code'] == 200){
    $price = $result['data']['close'];
}
```

Comment: "very slow to read" what do you mean by that?

Comment: Your code is just fine, there maybe two reasons for that, the target server is slow or the response is very huge to get or maybe your internet connection is slow